# SQL Server Pass column name as where clause parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to pass the column name as where clause parameter.

```
     SELECT RP.Saturday,
            RP.Sunday,
            RP.Monday,
            RP.Tuesday,
            RP.Wednesday,
            RP.Thursday,
            RP.Friday,
            RP.SalesMan,
            MC.CustomerID,
            MC.CustomerName
       FROM RoutePlan RP
  FULL JOIN MasterCustomer MC 
         ON RP.CustomerID = MC.CustomerID
      WHERE MC.CreatedBy = 'abc'
        AND RP.Thursday = 1;
```

I can get the name from this query

```
(Select DATENAME(DW,GETDATE()))
```

but how I can pass the day name as a parameter(column name). because the day name is a string and search variable data format is an integer so the query is showing

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Thursday' to data type int."

Comment: can you also add your where clause, eaxcatly how you would like to send

Comment: add that portion which you get error

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking here. Try to elaborate more and explain your goal.

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers in SQL. However, it seems like an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Please edit your question to add sample data as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) and desired results.

Comment: If you want int value from day name use this `select {fn DAYOFWEEK( getdate() )}=5`

Comment: i want to get the result day basis, for example, today is thursday, i got column names all the week name that you can see the select statement. so where will be thursday=1 and whoever createdby. so how i can pass this "thursday" as parameter and get the result. i hope you can understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more way to do that, but it depends on local settings on the server, so you want to use [`Set DateFirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to 7:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;

SELECT RP.Saturday,
       RP.Sunday,
       RP.Monday,
       RP.Tuesday,
       RP.Wednesday,
       RP.Thursday,
       RP.Friday,
       RP.SalesMan,
       MC.CustomerID,
       MC.CustomerName
FROM RoutePlan RP
     FULL JOIN MasterCustomer MC ON RP.CustomerID = MC.CustomerID
WHERE MC.CreatedBy = 'abc'
AND (ISNULL(RP.Saturday, 0) * 1) +
    (ISNULL(RP.Sunday, 0) * 2) +
    (ISNULL(RP.Monday, 0) * 3) +
    (ISNULL(RP.Tuesday, 0) * 4) + 
    (ISNULL(RP.Wednesday, 0) * 5) + 
    (ISNULL(RP.Thursday, 0) * 6) + 
    (ISNULL(RP.Friday, 0) * 7) = DATEPART((weekday,GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can logically apply a parameter on the name of the day like this:

```
DECLARE @day VARCHAR(10) = DATENAME(DW, GETDATE())

SELECT RP.Saturday,
       RP.Sunday,
       RP.Monday,
       RP.Tuesday,
       RP.Wednesday,
       RP.Thursday,
       RP.Friday,
       RP.SalesMan,
       MC.CustomerID,
       MC.CustomerName
FROM RoutePlan RP
     FULL JOIN MasterCustomer MC ON RP.CustomerID = MC.CustomerID
WHERE MC.CreatedBy = 'abc'
  AND (
    (@day = 'Saturday' and RP.Saturday = 1) OR
    (@day = 'Sunday' and RP.Sunday = 1) OR
    (@day = 'Monday' and RP.Monday = 1) OR
    (@day = 'Tuesday' and RP.Tuesday = 1) OR
    (@day = 'Wednesday' and RP.Wednesday = 1) OR
    (@day = 'Thursday' and RP.Thursday = 1) OR
    (@day = 'Friday' and RP.Friday = 1)
  )
```

Using this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE MasterCustomer(CustomerID int, CustomerName varchar(25), CreatedBy varchar(25))
CREATE TABLE RoutePlan(CustomerID int, Saturday bit, Sunday bit, Monday bit, Tuesday bit, Wednesday bit, Thursday bit, Friday bit, SalesMan varchar(25))

INSERT INTO MasterCustomer (CustomerID, CustomerName, CreatedBy) VALUES (1, 'Customer1', 'abc')
INSERT INTO RoutePlan (CustomerID, Saturday, SalesMan) VALUES (1, 1, 'John')
INSERT INTO RoutePlan (CustomerID, Thursday, SalesMan) VALUES (1, 1, 'Joe')
```

Running this on a Thursday will return 1 row where RP.Thursday = 1:

```
Saturday    Sunday  Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  SalesMan    CustomerID  CustomerName
NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        1           NULL    Joe         1           Customer1
```

Comment: thats it but still need to find the day. becuase it will change day to day. you are genius. less explanation you got what the student want. thank you sir.

Comment: @NAJEEB great! I edited my answer to populate the day parameter with the name of the current day.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO. According to the RDBMS philosophy the best way is to create a referenced table for instance `DayOfWeek(dayNum int not null, dayName nvarchar (16) not null)`
Then you just insert there all the values and can use it in a main clause in a `join` section

And just in case - keep in mind, that not all countries have the same order of days numeration.